# Retrieving Data Firebase Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to retrieve some strings from the database after sign in, however my code never ends up running everything. Here it is below:

```
@IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: EmailTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!, completion: {
        (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("no error")
            if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                print("no error")
                //if user.isEmailVerified == true {
                    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
                    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        print("no error")
                        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let type = snapDict?["type"] as? String ?? ""
                        print(type)
                })
                //} else {
                    //error email isnt verified
                //}
            }
        } else {
            print(" error")
            if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                switch errCode {
                case .errorCodeInvalidEmail: break
                    //invalid email
                case .errorCodeUserNotFound: break
                    //user doesnt exist
                case .errorCodeWrongPassword: break
                    //incorrect password
                default: break
                    //error occured
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

print(type) never ends up being printed, but everything else does. I'm not sure why this is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not when you retrieve the user but when you set the data in the database.

You can see in your database the user key is **Optional("YOUR_KEY")** but it should be **YOUR_KEY**.

You must unwrap the userId before set the user data.

Something like that :

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

if let user = user {
    let userId = user.uid;

    // Use the userId
}
```